# (Shared)Pointer to Singelton

Tags: c++, singleton

I found this implementation of a Singleton. 
How can I make a pointer or a shared pointer to this?`

And why is this not working?
auto test = Singleton::Instance();

```
class Singleton
{
public:
static Singleton & Instance()
{
    static Singleton myInstance;
    return myInstance;
}

// delete copy and move constructors and assign operators
Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;             // Copy construct
Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;                  // Move construct
Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;  // Copy assign
Singleton& operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;      // Move assign

// Any other public methods

protected:
Singleton()
{
}

~Singleton()
{
}

// And any other protected methods.
};
```

Comment: Why would you need a shared pointer in this case? This sounds you are trying to solve a XY-problem. The test code could be fixed using a reference: `auto& test = Singleton::Instance();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And why is this not working? auto test = Singleton::Instance();

If you take a look at the compilation error, it'll tell you.

```
main.cpp:31:37: error: use of deleted function 'Singleton::Singleton(const Singleton&)'
```

You're trying to copy the object. But the copy constructor is deleted and therefore the type is not copyable.

You probably intended to make a reference instead of a copy:

```
auto& test = Singleton::Instance();
```

> How can I make a pointer ... to this?

You can assign a pointer to the singleton by taking it's address with the address-of operator:

```
auto* test = &Singleton::Instance();
```

> or a shared pointer

You cannot have shared pointers to objects with static storage - unless you use a special deleter, but such shared pointer is of little use. Since your singleton has static storage, you wouldn't want to use a shared pointer. You could modify your singleton to keep a statically stored shared pointer to dynamically allocated object. Then you could have a shared pointer.

Comment: you'll want to give a shared_ptr a null-deleter

Comment: Ah - perfect. Make sense.
Thank you very much :)

Is that a good way to make a Singleton?

Comment: With this way it is not possible to delete the object manually - right? Or is there any way?

Comment: @Waterplant you can only delete objects manually if you allocated them dynamically. Your singleton is allocated statically, so no.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the shared pointer as a member of the class, and return that?

So you'd have

```
shared_ptr<Singleton> Instance()
{
    if(!myInstance)
    {
        myInstance.reset(new Singleton());
    }

    return myInstance;
}

private:
    shared_ptr<Singleton> myInstance;
```

Comment: I tried it - but I am getting the message:
"cannot access private member declared in class"

Answer (score 0):

A raw pointer: `Singleton* ptr = &Singleton::Instance();` or `auto ptr = &Singleton::Instance();`

A reference: `Singleton& ref = Singleton::Instance();` or `auto& ref = Singleton::Instance();`

You should not use shared pointers (as you do not own singleton object). Not without changing singleton class accordingly.

---

Why yoour code didn't work: `auto` deduces type to be a value type and tries to copy result of `instance()`. As `Singleton` is uncopiable, this fails.